# Value of $c$ that makes $c(\bar X (1 - \bar X))$ an unbiased estimator of $p(1 - p)$

Tags: probability, expected-value

I need to find the value of $c$ that makes $c(\bar X (1 - \bar X))$ an unbiased estimator of $p(1 - p)$.

I am confused about how to do this. I want to say that the value of $c$ must be $1$ because $E(\bar X) = \frac{\mu}{n} = \frac{np}{n} = p$, but that seems too easy.

Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are making a mistake by "accepting" the answer by herb steinberg.

Comment: The error in your reasoning is that $\mathbb E[\overline{X}]=p$ doesn't imply $\mathbb E[\overline{X}(1-\overline{X})]=p(1-p)$. In general, $\mathbb E[AB]\neq\mathbb E[A]\cdot\mathbb E[B]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\operatorname{var}(\overline X) = \frac{p(1-p)} n
$$
So
$$
\operatorname E(\overline X^2) = p^2 + \frac{p(1-p)} n
$$
$$
\operatorname E(\overline X(1-\overline X)) = p - p^2 - \frac p n + \frac {p^2} n = \left( 1 - \frac 1 n \right) p(1-p).
$$

So the value of $c$ that you need is the reciprocal of $1 - \dfrac 1 n.$

Comment: $var(\bar{X})=\frac{p(1-p)}{n}$ is true for Bernoulli distribution.  However the question doesn't include that condition.

Comment: @herbsteinberg : And yet it is probable that the failure to include that condition was simply a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

$E(\bar{X}^2)=\frac{1}{n}E(X^2)+\frac{n-1}{n}p^2=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}+p^2$  You need  to take into account the $\sigma^2$ term to get $c$, since $E(\bar{X}(1-\bar{X}))=p(1-p)-\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$.

Assuming a Bernoulli distribution $\sigma^2=p(1-p)$  so that $E(\bar{X}(1-\bar{X}))=\frac{n-1}{n}p(1-p)$ leading to $c=\frac{n}{n-1}$ with max $c=2$ at $n=2$.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. What value of $c$ do you think this leads to?

Comment: (Remember that the value of $c$ must be the same for all values of $p$ or of $\sigma^2.$) $\qquad$

Comment: Note additional material.